# Upload images to the server using Alamofire

Tags: swift, image, upload, retrofit, alamofire

The following problem arose, the fact is that sometimes images are not uploaded to the server. All the data is correct, the image is present, the variables are arranged in the correct order, the function reports a successful upload, but sometimes the images still do not reach the server. There are no such problems with the Retorfit library, but with Alamofire it often arises. I can not figure out yet why.

```
class func write_photo(params:[String:String],image:UIImage, in_position:String, completion:_ js:String, _ success:Bool -> Void, failure:_ errorMessage:String,_ failure:Bool -> Void) {
    let url = BaseURL + "xdb_items.write_photo"
    let URL = try! URLRequest(url: url, method: .post)
    let in_idclient = params["in_idclient"]
    let in_iditem = params["in_iditem"]
    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)!
    sessionManagerImage.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append((in_idclient?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)!, withName: "in_idclient")
        multipartFormData.append((in_iditem?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)!, withName: "in_iditem")
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "in_filename", fileName: "photo", mimeType: "image/png")
        multipartFormData.append((in_position.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!), withName: "in_position")
    }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: {
        encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.response { response in
                completion("", true)
            }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")
        }
    })
}
```

my friends, when I did the application rollout, the Xcode issued such a warning on the id_item variable: **could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. at real iPhone device** maybe this is the problem

found an error, status code 500, because of what it can occur?

Postman work great! Screenshot Postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzy3T.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwbtv.png)

Code that Postman offers, but I need Alamofire:

```
    import Foundation

let headers = [
  "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXrZu0gW",
  "Authorization": "Basic dXXXXXXXXXXXX=",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "Postman-Token": "2c1bXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4e"
]
let parameters = [
  [
    "name": "in_filename",
    "fileName": "/home/iv/Рабочий стол/Скрины/Скрин6.png"
  ],
  [
    "name": "in_idclient",
    "value": "516"
  ],
  [
    "name": "in_iditem",
    "value": "1232"
  ],
  [
    "name": "in_position",
    "value": "5"
  ]
]

let boundary = "----WeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXrZu0gW"

var body = ""
var error: NSError? = nil
for param in parameters {
  let paramName = param["name"]!
  body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
  body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(paramName)\""
  if let filename = param["fileName"] {
    let contentType = param["content-type"]!
    let fileContent = String(contentsOfFile: filename, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    if (error != nil) {
      print(error)
    }
    body += "; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n"
    body += "Content-Type: \(contentType)\r\n\r\n"
    body += fileContent
  } else if let paramValue = param["value"] {
    body += "\r\n\r\n\(paramValue)"
  }
}

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://XXXXXXXXXX:XXXX/XX/xdb_items.write_photo")! as URL,
                                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = postData as Data

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: my friends, when I did the application rollout, the Xcode issued such a warning on the id_item variable: **could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. at real iPhone device**  maybe this is the problem

Comment: found an error, status code 500, because of what it can occur?

Answer (score 0):

try instead of this

```
multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "in_filename", fileName: "photo", mimeType: "image/png")
```

to

```
multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "profile_photo")
```

may be this will helpful for you

Comment: found an error, status code 500, because of what it can occur?

Comment: Error code 500 usually denotes internal server error. Try the same through postman if error persists then you need to get in touch with DB guys

Comment: ask your api creator which type of data they get and in which format they accept that is jsonencode or array format or can you give the postman screenshot then we understand properly what should we do

Comment: problem create in header called **boundary**

Answer (score 0):

```
let imageData : Data! = (UIImage converted to Data) 

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }, to: NSURL(string: "http://URL you want to upload it to")! as URL)
            { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                   //Success
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    //Failure
                }
            }
```

Comment: found an error, status code 500, because of what it can occur?